# Unity NavMeshAgent Starts To Go a Different Direction When Collides With Player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

So I have a capsule as my NavMeshAgent (for now) and it follows the player and avoids walls, but when the player collides with the capsule, the capsule starts to wander off randomly. My code for the NavMeshAgent is the following:  [SerializeField]
    Transform destination;

```
NavMeshAgent navMeshAgent;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void FixedUpdate()
{
    navMeshAgent = this.GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();

    if (navMeshAgent == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("The nav mesh agent component is not attached to " + gameObject.name);
    }

    else if (navMeshAgent.enabled == true)
    {
        SetDestination();
    }
}

private void SetDestination()
{
    if (destination != null)
    {
        Vector3 targetVector = destination.transform.position;
        navMeshAgent.SetDestination(targetVector);
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        SetDestination();
    }
}
```

Highly appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the SetDestination(Vector3) with a SetDestination(transform.position) and linking the transform to a child gameobject of the object you're trying to follow.

The script also may be confused by your void and unity's void. Try renaming the function.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try this.

Comment: They still wander around, unless I misunderstood what you meant by linking the transform the child gameobject of the object I am trying to follow. What I did was put the Player gameobject into an empty game object and set that to the agents destintaion. Is that correct?

Comment: Try this tutorial on NavMesh: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CHV1ymlw-P8